# are there any implementations of coap-http or mqtt-http cross proxies available which can process thing descriptions?

Tags: web-of-things

I am using the node-wot browser library and I would like to connect IoT-devices communicating via MQTT and CoAP to the browser. As the browser/ library is not capable of communicating via MQTT or CoAP, are there any implementations of HTTP-CoAP or HTTP-MQTT proxies available which can process thing descriptions?

The idea would be to have a proxy where I could connect my device to, simply by providing a w3c wot thing description. Ideally the proxy would create another thing description which I could use to connect the browser to the proxy via HTTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check out the [shadow-thing project](https://github.com/tum-esi/shadow-thing) for an existing implementation but it is rather easy to this yourself with node-wot:

1. Fetch the TD of the Thing you want to proxy and consume it to create a consumed thing.
2. Take that TD and put it into the produce() method.
3. Add handlers for all the affordances
4. In each handler make the appropriate call to the consumed Thing.
5. Resolve the messages you get via your exposed Thing so that they are returned to your consumer.

Answer (score 1):

For me the requirements are not that clear.

The open source project Eclispe/Californium comes with coap2http cross proxy functionality (and also http2coap). You may try it [demo-apps/cf-proxy2](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/tree/master/demo-apps/cf-proxy2)